# Efficient query for updating element tags

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, performance

I am trying to create/add/delete tags all in one motion. I want to take an array of tag names and an element ID and efficiently update that element to have only the tags in the array.

I have 3 tables as shown below.

Elements:

```
|id|stuff|
|--|-----|
|1 | ... |
|2 | ... |
```

Tags:

```
|id|name|
|--|----|
|1 | pg |
|2 |node|
```

tag_map:

```
|id|element_id|tag_id|
|--|----------|------|
|1 |    2     |  1   |
|2 |    2     |  2   |
```

At the start of the operation, the element can have any number of tags assigned to it. The operation will start with an array of tag names and an element ID. At the end of the operation, I want the element with that element id to be assigned to only the tags passed in in that array. The array may have tags that have not yet been created yet in the tags table and therefore need to be inserted.

Here is my dumbed down, not optimized solution.

```
BEGIN;
    INSERT INTO tags (name)
    VALUES (''),(''),('')...
    ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;

    DELETE FROM tag_map
    WHERE element_id = 'myElemID';

    WITH tag_ids AS (
        SELECT id FROM tags
        WHERE name IN ('','',''...)
    )
    INSERT INTO tag_map (element_id, tag_id)
    SELECT ('myElemID', tag_ids);
COMMIT;
```

I'm sure there is a more efficient way to accomplish this same thing. Maybe even possible to do in one query? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What version of Postgres are you using? You could use `MERGE`.

Comment: I'm using postgres 13.7 so Merge is not available to me

Comment: Don't think it is possible to do it in one query only in one transaction

Answer (score 0):

Assuming an example structure:

```sql
create table elements (id serial primary key, stuff text);
create table tags     (id serial primary key, name text);
create table tag_map  (id serial primary key,
                       element_id integer references elements(id),
                       tag_id     integer references tags(id));
insert into elements (stuff) values ('e1'),('e2'),('e3');
insert into tags     (name)  values ('t1'),('t2'),('t3'),('t4');
insert into tag_map  (element_id, tag_id)  values (1,1),(1,2),(2,4);
```

You can do that using [`WITH` (common table expressions)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html), in one operation:

```sql
with 
 delete_tag_map_by_element as (  
    delete from tag_map tm 
    using elements e
    where tm.element_id=e.id 
    and   e.stuff='e2'
    returning 'deleted' as operation,tm.*)
,tag_ids_from_names as (
    select id
    from   tags
    where   name in ('t2','t3'))--tag list goes here
,insert_tag_map as (
    insert into tag_map (element_id, tag_id)
    select 3, --target element to be tagged goes here
         id
    from tag_ids_from_names
    returning 'inserted' as operation,*)
select * from delete_tag_map_by_element
  union
select * from insert_tag_map;
```

[Online demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/KNxVRjWo)

---

About the comments: some PostgreSQL 15 [`MERGE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-merge.html) functionality is available to you in PostgreSQL 12 in the form of [`insert...on conflict do update`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) but it doesn't make sense here because of `tag_map.id` field, which I assume is the table primary key. If you ditched that column and set up the pk as

```sql
create table tag_map2 (
  element_id integer references elements(id),
  tag_id integer references tags(id),
  primary key (element_id,tag_id));
```

You could use the `WHEN MATCHED` and `WHEN NOT MATCHED` handling in [`MERGE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-merge.html) to delete tag-element mappings missing in the new set. [`insert...on conflict do update`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) could leave existing mappings and add new ones, but without a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) it wouldn't have a way to delete outdated mappings - which is why it's mostly referred to as `UPSERT`, not fully covering all uses of `MERGE`.